# CKEditor links: Set (different) default target for each link type

Tags: ckeditor

In ckeditor I have set the default link target to be _blank. This works fine when the link type is 'URL' but isn't ideal for anchor or email links.

Is there a way of setting a different default link target for each of the link types?

Or alternatively just keeping the target tab visible when you have changed to the anchor tab?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Do you use CKEditor 5? How did you do target = _blank by default? i don't see such option